# Bootstrap selectpicker not aligned

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I create a small form using panel, but my selectpicker is not aligned with the other fields. (image below)

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <h3 align="center">Signature</h3>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="signatureName" class="col-lg-2">Signature Name:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SignatureName" id="SignatureName" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="signatureName" class="col-lg-2">Font:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <select id="signatureFont" name="signatureFont" onchange="changeFont(this);" class="selectpicker">
                         <option value="">Select</option>
                         <option value="Aguafina Script">Aguafina Script</option>
                         <option value="Alex Brush">Alex Brush</option>
                         <option value="Bilbo">Bilbo</option>
                         <option value="Condiment">Condiment</option>
                         <option value="Great Vibes">Great Vibes</option>
                         <option value="Herr Von Muellerhoff">Herr Von Muellerhoff</option>
                         <option value="Kristi">Kristi</option>
                         <option value="Meddon">Meddon</option>
                         <option value="Monsieur La Doulaise">Monsieur La Doulaise</option>
                         <option value="Norican">Norican</option>
                         <option value="Parisienne">Parisienne</option>
                         <option value="Permanent Marker">Permanent Marker</option>
                         <option value="Sacramento">Sacramento</option>
                         <option value="Yellowtail">Yellowtail</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="displaySignature" class="col-lg-2">Signature:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="displaySignature" id="displaySignature" readonly />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value=" Sign " />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({});
    });
</script>
```

Is there any settings that I should apply to the select picker? I am using bootstrap-select.min for my select picker

Thanks

Comment: Did you inspect it and see whats going on with the css, or should we be doing that for you?

Comment: Did you think too much to give this answer? I'm new with bootstrap, if I knew how to fix it, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: This isn't bootstrap specific, it's css

Comment: What part of the CSS is wrong?